# Perform operations over a list of dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I wrote a script with one dataframe `df1`  and applied to it a lot of operations. For example:

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': ''})
df1.iloc[:,0] = re.search('\d{2}', df1.columns[3]).group(0)
```

But now I have a list of dataframes `dfs`. Is it possible, and so how can I apply all operations to a list of dataframes?

I tried

```
for df in dfs:
    df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': ''})
    df.iloc[:,0] = re.search('\d{2}', df.columns[3]).group(0)
```

But it is overwriting and I get only the last dataframe from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start the loop, you initialize an empty `df_total`. At the end of each loop, you concatenate the current `df` to the `df_total`, so that this last grows up each loop, saving your previous dataframes. An example of code:

```
df_total = pd.DataFrame()

for df in dfs:
    df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': ''})
    df.iloc[:,0] = re.search('\d{2}', df.columns[3]).group(0)
    df_total = pd.concat([df_total , df], ignore_index = True)
```